# JPA Hibernate no encuentra logical column name for a @JoinColum cuabndo está referenced from referencingColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo la entidad **@Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CO_CONTRACT")
public class Contract {

@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TRAVELDATETYPE", referencedColumnName = "CODEVALUE")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT", value = "'TRAVELDATETYPE'"))})
private BusinessElementValue travelDateType;

}
```

Y **BusinessElementValue**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL")
public class BusinessElementValue extends AuditInfo {

@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
private BusinessElement businessElement;

@Id
@Column(name = "CODEVALUE")
private String codeValue;

}
```

Esto falla al arrancar porque

> Unable to find column with logical name: GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT in GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:858)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)

Pero si cambio a en **BusinessElementValue**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
private String businessElement;
```

Funciona.

Porque falla en el primer caso?

Puedo referenciar una columna que es una `@JoinColumn` in otra `@Entity` ?

Comment: El 
@Column(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT") tiene que ser el mismo nombre que tienes en la base de datos

Comment: @Raul Cachaco Si lo es. Creo que no me has entendido cuando es `@Column` reconoce la columna y recone la `@Join` en Contract, cuando es `@JoinColumn` no reconoce la columna en Contract y dice que no encuentra una columna con nombre logico el BussinesElementVall.

Comment: El error dice que no existe ninguna columna  GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL en la tabla GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT tienes que poner el id de esa tabla

Comment: No, dice lo contrario que no existe ninguna columna GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT en la tabla GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL

Answer (score 1):

finalmente lo he resulto.

Hay que crear un @EmbebedId con la clava compuesta:

```
@Embeddable
public class BusinessElementValuePK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
    private BusinessElement businessElement;


    @Column(name = "CODEVALUE")
    private String codeValue;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL")
public class BusinessElementValue extends AuditInfo {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BusinessElementValuePK businessElementValuePK;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CO_CONTRACT")
public class Contract {

  @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TRAVELDATETYPE", referencedColumnName = "CODEVALUE")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT", value = "'TRAVELDATETYPE'"))})
    private BusinessElementValue travelDateType;

}
```